# how to set cookies in _layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

When the site starts then I have a function that checks if there are user cookies-

```
        foreach (var cookie in HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies)
    {
        if (cookie.Key == "OrderLoginDetails")
        {

            Customer.Cookie = cookie.Value;
        }
    }
```

And it works great!

The problem starts when I try to make new cookies ...

How can I make new cookies in the Layout file?

I tried like this-

```
 if (Customer.Cookie == null)
    {
        var newCust = Customer.newCustomer();
        var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
        {
            Path = "/",
            HttpOnly = false,
            IsEssential = true, //<- there
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1),
        };
        Response.Cookies.Append("OrderLoginDetails", Customer.CustomerCode + Customer.CustomerMail, cookieOptions);


    }
```

But it does not work.

Best regards

Comment: what do you mean by ***it does not work***? is there any error? have you tried debugging the code to make sure that the `Response.Cookies.Append` is executed?

Comment: I got 2 errors -
1. The name 'Response' does not exist in the current context
2. The type or namespace name 'CookieOptions' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The code is in the layout page, it's the problem... but I don't know another way to set cookies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code is in a Layout or other Razor view file, you use the `Context` property to access the `HttpContext` e.g.

```
foreach (var cookie in Context.Request.Cookies)
{
    if (cookie.Key == "OrderLoginDetails")
    {
        Customer.Cookie = cookie.Value;
    }
}
```

And

```
Context.Response.Cookies.Append("OrderLoginDetails", Customer.CustomerCode + Customer.CustomerMail, cookieOptions);
```

Although if you want to execute this code for each page request, you might consider a Filter rather than embedding it in a layout page: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/filters